# jupyterhub stuck at kernel starting

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyterhub

I am trying to setup a jupyterhub for my home network.
The os is CentOS 7.
I followed the official website instructions and installed by conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterhub  # installs jupyterhub and proxy
conda install notebook  # needed if running the notebook servers locally
```

I changed the ip and port in the jupyterhub_config.py

```
c.JupyterHub.ip = '*'
c.JupyterHub.port = 8000
```

and open the firewall port 8000.

however, when I start the service and connect to it, the it always show `starting kernel, please wait`. I tried different solutions suggested online:
1. change browser.
2. clear catch.
3. downgrade tornado to 5.1.1.
None of them worked. 
Any suggestions?

below are the logs:

```
[I 2020-06-14 16:56:42.986 SingleUserNotebookApp handlers:153] Creating new notebook in 
[I 2020-06-14 16:56:42.991 SingleUserNotebookApp log:174] 201 POST /user/wzh/api/contents (wzh@::ffff:192.168.10.161) 6.32ms
[I 2020-06-14 16:56:43.258 SingleUserNotebookApp log:174] 200 GET /user/wzh/notebooks/Untitled1.ipynb?kernel_name=python3 (wzh@::ffff:192.168.10.161) 256.50ms
[I 2020-06-14 16:56:43.536 SingleUserNotebookApp log:174] 200 GET /user/wzh/api/config/notebook?_=1592125003444 (wzh@::ffff:192.168.10.161) 2.20ms
[I 2020-06-14 16:56:43.539 SingleUserNotebookApp log:174] 200 GET /user/wzh/api/config/common?_=1592125003445 (wzh@::ffff:192.168.10.161) 2.17ms
[I 2020-06-14 16:56:43.576 SingleUserNotebookApp log:174] 200 GET /user/wzh/api/contents/Untitled1.ipynb?type=notebook&_=1592125003446 (wzh@::ffff:192.168.10.161) 2.06ms
[I 2020-06-14 16:56:43.666 SingleUserNotebookApp log:174] 200 GET /user/wzh/api/contents/Untitled1.ipynb/checkpoints?_=1592125003447 (wzh@::ffff:192.168.10.161) 0.96ms
[I 2020-06-14 16:56:43.686 SingleUserNotebookApp kernelmanager:172] Kernel started: ee910a85-5afe-48b6-8a88-e30c29b63867
[I 2020-06-14 16:56:43.687 SingleUserNotebookApp log:174] 201 POST /user/wzh/api/sessions (wzh@::ffff:192.168.10.161) 20.65ms
[W 2020-06-14 16:56:43.696 SingleUserNotebookApp log:174] 404 GET /user/wzh/nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20200614165639 (wzh@::ffff:192.168.10.161) 7.93ms
```

#### The setup I have

1. Esxi 6.5.
2. CentOS 7.
3. conda 4.8.2.
4. jupyterhub 1.1.0.
5. Python 3.7

Comment: Can you please write what version of jupyterhub are you using?

Comment: also, what python version are you using?

Comment: I updated description

Comment: You can check whether the problem is with your installation simplay by using the Docker image instead of installing.
Did you check if you have /user/wzh/nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js
Also, you are saying that the kerne is stuck, but it seems like the kernel started, but the program is stuck.

Comment: in general I think this question is more appropriate to jupyterhub's github page